# How to set field type choice using csom (c#)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, csom

I have a field type: Choice (menu to choose from) which is not multichoice. How do I set a value?

I have found code for multiple choice but it doesn't seem to work for single choice.

Comment: You could set a value for a choice field as if it's a text field. item["ChoiceFieldName"] = "someVale"; item.Update()

Comment: Yes you are right !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You Can set it by updating the Item with the choice value, as below

```
newListItem["ChoiceFieldName"] = "ChoiceValue";
        newListItem.Update();

        clientContext.Load(newListItem);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But if you are assigning a Value which is not in the Choice Column, You need to create a choice value then assign it to the item.

Answer (score 12):

**Example 1**

Explicitly specify choice value:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
    var taskItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);

    taskItem["Status"] = "In Progress";
    taskItem.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Example 2**

Choose a value from field choice:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
     var taskItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
     var field = list.Fields.GetByTitle("Task Status");
     ctx.Load(field);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     var fieldStatus = ctx.CastTo<FieldChoice>(field);
     var values = fieldStatus.Choices;

     taskItem["Status"] = values[1]; //specify value by index 
     taskItem.Update();
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```